# interview question printing a floating point number

Tags: c, floating-point, printf

What's the output of the following program and why?

```
  #include <stdio.h>
  int main()
  {
   float a = 12.5;
   printf("%d\n", a);
   printf("%d\n", *(int *)&a);
   return 0;
  }
```

My compiler prints 0 and 1095237632. Why?

Comment: What do *you* think?

Comment: i guess &a should return the address of a which is cast to an int pointer (instead of a pointer to float) and then the pointer is dereferenced to access a..

Comment: Also, `*(int *)&a` breaks strict aliasing rules, so if anything does not happen because of the rest of the program, anything may happen because of that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In both cases you pass a bits representing floating-point values, and print them as decimal. The second case is the simple case, here the output is the same as the underlying representation of the floating-point number. (This assumes that the calling convention specified that the value of a `float` is passed the same way an `int` is, which is not guaranteed.)

However, in the first case, when you pass a `float` to a vararg function like `printf` it is promoted to a `double`. This mean that the value passed will be 64 bits, and `printf` will pick up either half of it (or perhaps garbage). In your case it has apparently picked up the 32 least significant bits, as they typically will be all zero after a `float` to `double` cast.

Just to make it absolutely clear, the code in the question is *not* valid C, as it's illegal to pass values to `printf` that does not match the format specifier.

Comment: Absolutely clear and then mixed meanings :) Surely "is not valid C"

Comment: @tinman, good spot, i've updated the answer with the missing "*not*" -- thanks!

Answer (score 7):

The memory referred to by `a` holds a pattern of bits which the processor uses to represent 12.5.  How does it represent it:  [IEEE 754](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).   What does it look like?   [See this calculator to find out: 0x4148000](http://babbage.cs.qc.edu/IEEE-754/Decimal.html).   What is that when interpreted as an int?  1095237632.

Why do you get a different value when you don't do the casting?  I'm not 100% sure, but I'd guess it's because compilers can use a [calling convention](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#x86-64_calling_conventions) which passes floating point arguments in a different location than integers, so when printf tries to find the first integer argument after the string, there's nothing predictable there.
 (Or more likely, as @Lindydancer points out, the float bits may be passed in the 'right' place for an int, but because they are first promoted to a double representation by extending with zeros, there are 0s where printf expects the first int to be.)

Comment: I think Lindydancer's argument is actually correct; wiki agrees that floats are always promoted to doubles (hence format's specifiers are all for doubles), and that is what generates the zeros. The arguments are passed via the stack, not registers. The compiler simply can't make that optimization, precisely because the function can accept any types.

Comment: Lindydancer may be correct in this case, at least for Windows compilers.  However, see Section 3.5.7 and Table 3.32 in the "[System V Application Binary Interface AMD64 Architecture Processor Supplement](http://x86-64.org/documentation/abi.pdf)", which describes the convention for 64 bit Linux.  It states that "assuming that all arguments are passed on the stack ... [does] not work on the AMD64 architecture because some arguments are passed in registers" and shows a different set of registers used for floating point than the ones used for general purpose.  So it could happen my way.

Comment: Wow; +1 for link. That must make some pretty trippy code inside varargs.cpp then. It's going to have to do some combination of peeking at stuff lower down the stack as well as checking various registers as it parses down the format string.

Answer (score 1):

This is because [floating point representation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point) (see [IEEE 754](http://steve.hollasch.net/cgindex/coding/ieeefloat.html) standard).

In short, set of bits, which makes 12.5 floating point value in IEEE 755 representation when interpreted as an integer will give you strange value which has not much in common with 12.5 value.

WRT to `0` from `printf("%d\n", a)` , this is internal undefined behavior for incorrect printf call.

Comment: thank you for your answer. I am trying to learn C and I always have problems with pointer casts. At the bit level, what happens when you cast between a pointer of type A to a related/unrelated type? (i am talking strictly about C casts). The content of the memory that the pointers point to remain the same yet they are accessed differently? Most literature on pointers deal with pointer arithmetic and an overview of casting and arrays etc etc but they never go deep enough...

Comment: can't see how this answers the question

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: the question was "why" and the answer is because this is how 12.5 is encoded using IEEE 754. There is no point in copy-paste  the standsrd specification in the answer.

Comment: `printf("%d\n", a);` prints 0. Why?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: because this is internal undefined behavior for incorrect printf call.

Comment: Add that to your answer then.